# How to change delegate in subclass? Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, delegates

I am currently looking for ways to better my code. The app talks to the server and retrieves several types of information: arrays of people, arrays of timestamps, etc. When I started writing code that talks to the server, I created a base WebService class that configures AFNetworking (URL, manager, etc) and has a delegate called in the blocks.

Every time I needed a new service, I created a new class that inherits from this class. Each class declares it's own protocol for the delegate to receive the data. About 90% of the protocol methods within this classes are marked as required because I want to make sure that the delegate is able to receive the data.

At this point I am refactoring code and I noticed that about half of my delegate protocols require a "successful" method and a "failed" method. I figured that all the functions that just need those two methods should be implemented in the parent class so as to have less protocols to conform to in my view controllers. I started the process, but when I change my delegate declaration from `id delegate` to `id<WebServiceDelegate> delegate`, all the child classes expect their delegate to conform to the WebServiceDelegate protocol and I get compile errors.

My goal is to only have child classes for the connections that DON'T need the success and fail method, so I don't want to just extend the protocol. Inheriting from NSObject instead of WebService also seems wasteful since I have to configure AFNetworking in all of them again (repeated code).

For now, I don't make the delegate conform to any protocol but I would like to enforce that. My only reasonable solution is to add another delegate to the child classes that conforms just to the child class's protocol, but I feel there should be a better one.

In summary my question is: how do I make a child class's delegate conform to a new protocol instead of the parent's protocol?

Sample Current Code:

```
// Parent Class
@interface WebService : NSObject 

@property (weak) id delegate;

// Child Class 
//   there's a few child class protocols that just implement this 2 methods
@protocol UploadServiceDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void) uploadServiceSuccess;
- (void) uploadServiceFailure;
@end

@interface UploadService : WebService

// Here is a more complicated protocol
@protocol ScheduleServiceDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void) scheduleServiceSuccess;
- (void) scheduleServiceFailure;

@optional
- (void) receiveSchedule: (NSArray*)schedules;
- (void) receiveURLForCertificate: (NSURL*) certURL;
@end
```

Sample ideal code, in this case, all the *Success and *Failure protocol declarations would no longer be needed since the methods that would call these would be implemented in the parent class:

```
@protocol WebServiceDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void) WebServiceSuccess;
- (void) WebServiceFailure;
@end

@interface DGWebService : NSObject 

@property (weak) id<WebServiceDelegate> delegate;
```

This way, the other protocols would only declare the methods that are needed, and make them `@required` instead of optional. This is the point where I think I need a new delegate property declaration:

```
@protocol ScheduleServiceDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void) receiveSchedule: (NSArray*)schedules;
- (void) receiveURLForCertificate: (NSURL*) certURL;
@end

// Delegate at this point:
@property (weak) id<WebServiceDelegate> delegate;
// Delegate I need:
@property (weak) id<ScheduleServiceDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: I'm confused by your explanation but it sounds like a very reasonable problem. Can you post some code to show an example?

Comment: @AdamPro13 I added sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `delegate` conform to both protocols like this:

```
@property (weak) id<ScheduleServiceDelegate, WebServiceDelegate> delegate;
```

or, you can have `ScheduleServiceDelegate` include the methods defined in `WebServiceDelegate` by defining it like this:

```
@protocol ScheduleServiceDelegate <NSObject, WebServiceDelegate>
```

Then you can go override the delegate in the subclass with just

```
@property (weak) id<ScheduleServiceDelegate> delegate;
```

Both of these ways should produce the results you want, unless I horribly misunderstood your question.

Comment: Your first option was my first thought, but I would have a lot of empty declarations because *Success and *Failure would never be called. The second one leaves me with empty declarations again, except in the service class instead of the view controller. I'm unclear on the third one, can you just override a property like that?

Comment: @gamda hmm, so what's wrong with keeping all you have but overriding the delegate in the subclass to be `id<ScheduleServiceDelegate>`? That way the delegate only needs to conform to `ScheduleServiceDelegate`, which is what you want?

Comment: That is exactly what I want! I just didn't imagine overriding a property was that simple. To summarize `@property (weak) id<ScheduleServiceDelegate> delegate;` in my child class will give that behavior?

Comment: @gamda Yep, overiding it means that the one in the subclass completely replaces the one in the superclass. It does seems a bit weird in this case though, but as long as you keep it safe with `respondsToSelector` checks it should be fine!

Comment: I tried overriding, but I get this warning: `Property type 'id'<OtherDelegate> is incompatible with the type 'id<WebServiceDelegate>' inherited from 'WebService'` I assume warnings are ok, but I would rather avoid them.